# Checking for null and 0 in multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in our Oracle DW with the following columns:

```
Turnover_In
Turnover_Out
Revenue_In
Revenue_Out
```

For both `Turnover_In` and `Turnover_Out`, I need to check to see if the value for either `Turnover_In` or `Turnover_Out` on that row is null or 0, and if that's the case, I need to output the value from `Revenue_In` or `Revenue_Out` into the corresponding column (`Turnover_In` and `Turnover_Out`).

Example of how source data looks:

```
Revenue In      Revenue out     Turnover in     Turnover out
                0               1000            1500
```

It should turn into the following:

```
Revenue In      Revenue out     Turnover in     Turnover out
1000            1500            1000            1500
```

I've tried the following now:

```
case
    when rev.revenue_in in (null,'0')
    or rev.revenue_out in (null,'0')
    then tur.turnover_in
end "Revenue in",
case
    when rev.revenue_in in (null,'0')
    or rev.revenue_out in (null,'0')
    then tur.turnover_out
end "Revenue out"
```

and

```
case
    when nvl(rev.revenue_in, '0') = '0'
    or nvl(rev.revenue_out, '0') = '0'
    then tur.turnover_in
end "Revenue in",
case
    when nvl(rev.revenue_in, '0') = '0'
    or nvl(rev.revenue_out, '0') = '0'
    then tur.turnover_out
end "Revenue out"
```

...But nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: you are missing the else everywhere?

Comment: Remember that nothing is equal or different to `NULL` in SQL. You have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Might i add the the `case` statement that you have written doesn´t reflect your original task. `Revenue_In in the corresponding column`, but you put `turnover_in` in the `revenue in` column. `I need to check to see if the value for either Turnover_In or Turnover_Out on that row is null or 0`, but you check for `revenue_in` and `revenue_out`. I feel like this should work, but you just missed the task.

Comment: Why are you using single quotes. Also, when you say nothing seems to work can you please clarify what result it is returning. Also, your question seems to be a bit ambiguous. When you say " I need to output the value from Revenue_In or Revenue_Out into the corresponding column (Turnover_In and Turnover_Out)" do you mean each column respectively?

Comment: The first method you used will not work because  you cannot use 'null' with 'in' statement. Please clarify what you mean by 'nothing seems to work' in regard with your the second  attempt: what is your input,  what is the desired output what is the actual output.

Comment: When I say that "nothing seems to work", I mean that the output dataset still contains rows where "Revenue in" and "Revenue" out have no values despite there being values in Turnover in/out.

Comment: @igneous the second solution that you provided works fine for the example that you give. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please check `nvl(trim(rev.revenue_in), '0') = '0'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a value is null or '0' you can do the following:

```
if nvl(rev.revenue_in,'0')='0'
then
```

The nvl() function will replace the null value with the value specified in the second parameter.

So your last solution should work.

```
case
    when nvl(rev.revenue_in, '0') = '0'
    or nvl(rev.revenue_out, '0') = '0'
    then tur.turnover_out
end "Revenue out"
```

There is no else in your case statement, so what should be returned if neither value is null of '0'?

Comment: The cross-DBMS alternative (if that matters) is `COALESCE`.

Comment: isn´t that exactly what he tried at the bottom of this select? (guess that´s the second method he tried)

Comment: Yes, I've essentially tried two different methods - one with nvl and one without.

Comment: @igneous Are these strings or numbers? You're treating everything as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it your way you need to use the below. In parameter will not evaluate NULL.

```
case
    when (rev.revenue_in is null or rev.revenue ='0'
    or rev.revenue_out is null  or rev.revenue_out ='0')
    then tur.turnover_in
end "Revenue in",
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 'proof of concept' that the solution **you** provided does exactly what you are describing in your example: just copy paste and run

```
select 
case
    when nvl(revenue_in, '0') = '0'
    or nvl(revenue_out, '0') = '0'
    then turnover_in
end "Revenue in",
case
    when nvl(revenue_in, '0') = '0'
    or nvl(revenue_out, '0') = '0'
    then turnover_out
end "Revenue out",
Turnover_in , Turnover_out 
from (select  null as Revenue_in,0 as Revenue_out,1000 as Turnover_in,1500 Turnover_out from dual) rev
```

Answer (score 0):

OK... referring to the original post and the solutions offered so far. (I haven't read everything, so please forgive me if some of this has been said already.)

```
...IN (NULL, ...)
```

doesn't work because `...x IN (1, 2, 3)` means `x = 1 OR x = 2 OR x = 3` (although the query optimizer will rewrite `IN` as a join, but the logical meaning is the same). But in Oracle and in the SQL standard, `NULL = NULL` is not TRUE; it is UNKNOWN. Indeed, two undefined values may or may not be equal, even if they are both called `NULL`. So this is why `IN` generally doesn't work for checking for `NULL`.

Then, the solutions with `NVL` (or `coalesce`) may work, that is a correct approach. I personally prefer to write out in full what the intent is; Raj_Te's solution is along those lines. Solutions with `NVL` tend to mask your logic and intent, and may be harder to maintain and debug for other developers in the future. Documentation can help, but it is best to write "self-documenting" code.

As others have noticed, the `case` statements everywhere are missing the `else` clause, so instead of returning the `revenue_in` and `revenue_out` values when they are NOT null or 0, the queries will return NULL in those columns.

I also find the requirement unclear... should the "IN" and "OUT" columns be treated separately? That's not what the OP tried. I offer below a solution for the problem the way it makes sense to me; the OP is free to modify if my interpretation (already clearly different from his/hers) is incorrect.

```
select case when rev.revenue_in  is null or rev.revenue_in  = 0 then tur.turnover_in 
                               else rev.revenue_in  end as revenue_in,
       case when rev.revenue_out is null or rev.revenue_out = 0 then tur.turnover_out
                               else rev.revenue_out end as revenue_out
```